# Entity Framework, Create 0-1 relation with existed entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an existing entity **User**. Now I am trying to create a new entity **Contact** with 0-1 relation with User.

```cs
class Contact
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int? UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual User TheUser{get; set;}
}
```

All suggestion involve about something like this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(t => t.TheUser)
    .WithOptionalDependent(u => u.TheConatct);
```

But this means we have to add *TheConatct* property to the existed *User* entity. Actually I do not want to make any modification to the existed entity. All what I need to define a foreign key form *Contact* to *User* entity and can access the *User* entity from *Contact* via *TheUser* property.

**Update:**
If I use ForeignKey attributes to annotate the property:

```
class Contact
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int? UserId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User TheUser{get; set;}
}
```

Then, the result of `ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()` will also include create statements for already existed tables (depending on the entities that have relations with User).

Of course we are talking about "Entity Framework 6 Code First", Also, I have the same problem with 1-1 relation.

The idea, I cannot alter the existing entity **User** to add additional property for the new entity **Contact**

I wonder if there is a way to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

Just use another overload:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(t => t.TheUser)
    .WithOptionalDependent();
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know which version of Entity Framework you are using and I assume you are using Code First, but you may have to consider using a one to many relationship instead of a 0-1.

I don't believe there is support for 0-1 in the way you want it, but you can simulate by having a one to many (even though your "many" will only ever by 1)

Comment: He is using version of EF which have 0-1 relationships.

Comment: Nope, that isn't mentioned.

Comment: Both overloads of `WithOptionalDependent` [exists since 6.0.0-beta1](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/1dc675f86d6c22a9f59b1085e07c08bb7c5063c2/src/EntityFramework/ModelConfiguration/Configuration/Properties/Navigation/HasX/OptionalNavigationPropertyConfiguration.cs).